# Persistent library instead of repeated imports django

Tags: python, django

I'm using Django to host a machine learning service, which returns predictions when queried with the parameters.

My problem is, everytime a new request comes in, it has to `import tensorflow` and all the various libraries all over again. This makes it really slow. (Tensorflow spews a bunch of messages whenever its imported and takes like 4 seconds to load)

Is there a way to make the libraries and models persistent?

Current Architecture (Only that service):

```
main_app/
    manage.py
    classifiers/
        __init__.py
        util.py
        views.py
        lstm_predictor.py
```

util.py: (Tensorflow is reloaded everytime a new request comes in!)

```
from sklearn.externals import joblib
import pandas as pd
import xgboost as xgb
from keras.models import load_model
from keras.preprocessing import sequence
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
import os,calendar,re
import logging
from lstm_predictor import lstm_predict
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

# Load models here to avoid reload every time
ensemble_final_layer = joblib.load("final_ensemble_layer.pkl")
text_processor = joblib.load("text_processor.pkl")
lstm = load_model("LSTM_2017-07-18_V0")
```

views.py

```
import json, pdb, os, hashlib
import logging

from django.core.serializers.json import DjangoJSONEncoder
from django.http.response import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from classifiers.util import *

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


@csrf_exempt
def predict(request):
    result = get_prediction(params)
    result_hash = {"routing_prediction":result}
    data = json.dumps(result_hash, cls = jangoJSONEncoder)
    return HttpResponse(data, content_type="application/json")
```

Is there somewhere I can shift the imports to, so that its only loaded once when the app starts?

Thank you! :)

Comment: It will only load once as modules are singletons, but you will run several processes when you deploy it using `uwsgi` or similar, so it will load once for each process.

Comment: @Grimmy Hello, thanks for your reply! It doesnt. Looking at the logs, tensorflow reloads everytime a new request comes in. (Tensorflow gives a bunch of messages when you first import it)

Comment: Does that also happen when you import `util` multiple times in `./manage.py shell`? That would be weird.

Comment: @Grimmy No it doesnt. Hmm could it be due to my import * in views.py? (updated question)

Comment: I would manually run `get_predictions` in `./manage.py shell` and see what happens. Also remember that python modules are singletons, so anything in the root level of the module only runs on the first import.

Comment: remove all unnecessary imports in your source and try running with Gunicorn with few workers instead of webserver as I see its usage is internal and not so many users.

Comment: @Wboy Are you running this in debug mode locally (ONE django process) or is this deployed somewhere using multiple processes? I would seriously consider moving the tensorflow work into workers using for example `celery`. Then your api calls will not be blocked and you just need to fetch the result of the job when it's flagged as completed. You also have the ability to scale up and down (single or multiple servers)

Comment: @Grimmy Deployed on heroku. I get the "Using tensorflow backend" message with every request. hmm..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not really an answer directly to the problem, but points out a potentially critical issue when making web apis that relies on doing memory and/or time hungry processes in Django views directly.

Web apis are supposed to be light and respond as quick as possible. They should also be easy to scale up with more processes without costing too much resources.

When using tensorflow in django directly, each django process will initialise their own tensorflow module and data files. These processes also tend to be restarted based on rules in the master process, but I don't know what the default behaviour is on Heroku. (I'm guessing they use `uwsgi` or `gunicorn`)

A better way is to move the work to separate worker processes. These processes waits for incoming work on a queue. Your `predict` view will just push a new job to the queue and return a unique `job_id` in the response (taking only a few milliseconds). The client using the api can then periodically pull the status of that `job_id`. When the job is completed successfully, it returns the json result.

This way you can have a really light and responsive api server. The number of workers can be scaled up and down depending on the needs. The workers can also run on a different server/container.

One way of achieving this is using `django_celery`, but there are probably many other options.

Answer (score 1):

Django does *not* import modules on each request. It logs once for each process. Normally, your server will start up multiple processes to serve your site; each one will import tensorflow - and any other modules - once only.

Comment: Hi @Daniel, So if I understand you correctly - even if i see the "Using tensorflow backend" message with new requests, its because a new process is being spun up to handle it?

Comment: @Wboy I'd say that's probably the case. I've added a comment on that in my question as well. I suspect maybe Heroku killing the process because it's slow or use too much memory. Rules for that can probably be configured.